Template Syntax Error when using Django allauth
I encountered this error when trying to improve the UI of login and signup pages..
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/logout/ 'slippers' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: account admin_list admin_modify admin_urls allauth allauth_ui cache i18n l10n log socialaccount static tz widget_tweaks
i had already installed the following packages:
django-allauth==65.2.0
django-allauth-ui==1.5.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.5.0

contents of project's settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # third-party apps
    "allauth_ui",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "widget_tweaks",
]

I just tried to reinstall the packages and it's still Template Error :(

According to the docs for allauth_ui - "django-allauth-ui depends on jazzband/django-widget-tweaks and mixxorz/slippers to render templates. Make sure to install both packages and add them to the INSTALLED_APPS."
Looks like you have only installed django-widget-tweaks.

Thank you for the feedback. I have added "slippers" to the INSTALLED_APPS list and it works now :)

just to complete the solution.. i also added "slippers" to the list of packages that needs to be installed as part of my requirements.txt.. pip install slippers
